# How to change ttk widget layout when state changes?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

Python source includes [a ttk demo](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Demo/tkinter/ttk/notebook_closebtn.py) which adds close buttons to ttk.Notebook tabs. It uses `style element create` and `style layout` to position an image to the tab.

With `style map` I can specify different properties for a widget depending on its state. Can I somehow also change the layout dynamically so that the close button is shown only on active tab?

(I know I can specify different images for the element depending on the state of the element itself, but I'd like to take into account the state of the container of the element.)